# close position after 'x' days

Tags: pine-script, back-testing

i've this basic strategy on pinescript that enter a position based on the crossover of 2 moving averages. what i would do is this: 
when the cross occurs enter a long/short (weather on is a bull or bear cross)
exit the position 3 candles later.
i've tried with the function 'barssince' but i'm not very good at coding.
this is my strategy:

````
strategy("MovingAvg2Line Cross", overlay=true, initial_capital=10000)
fastLength = input(50)
slowLength = input(200)
price = close

mafast = sma(price, fastLength)
maslow = sma(price, slowLength)

if (crossover(mafast, maslow))
    strategy.entry("MA2CrossLE", strategy.long, comment="MA2CrossLE")

if (crossunder(mafast, maslow))
    strategy.entry("MA2CrossSE", strategy.short, comment="MA2CrossSE") ```
````

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the end. It detects changes in the number of open trades and counts bars from then:

```
strategy.close_all(when = barssince(change(strategy.opentrades)) == 2)
```

Comment: thank you it worked properly i've also noticed that the crossover enter position occurs with 1 candle delay from the real moving averages touch. do you know how to anticipate it

Comment: See `process_orders_on_close=true` [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy).

Comment: With v5 the syntax has changed slightly to: strategy.close_all(when = ta.barssince(ta.change(strategy.opentrades)) == 2)

Comment: y, correct. Thx for the update.